# Make use of golang- Debian packages in Go programming

Tags: go, module, package, debian

To understand this Go question need to understand the gist of Go modules Debian packaging a bit first. Basically, the Go module Debian packages are so designed that they can only be used by Debian packages themselves, but not for our daily Go `import`.

However, because they are just files within my OS file system, there are surely ways that we can make use of the Debian packages in our daily Go `import`. Has anyone successfully done that before?

The reason I'm asking is that, there are many many github repos that contains HUGE modules, but what I want is only a tiny/small portion of it, while that portion happens to have already been packed as a Debian package. I.e., using `go get` will get me huge code base that I mostly don't need, while `apt get` can get me just what I need, if I can make use of it.

Comment: "there are many many github repos that contains HUGE modules, but what I want is only a tiny/small portion of it, while that portion happens to have already been packed as a Debian package" care to elaborate?

Comment: Please don't do what you're trying. You'll end up with outdated versions. And if what yous say is accurate, you're liable to end up with partial versions. Don't fight the tools. Disks are cheap.

Comment: Unless debian packages complete Go "modules" into the cache or through a proxy, you're just getting some files with versions unknown to the go toolchain. You cannot use modules with random local files. You could continue to use gopath, if the files are correctly structured around their imports, which seems unlikely as there would be no need to distribute only part of the go source for packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to *append* `/usr/share/gocode` to your `GOPATH` environment variable (after your own private Go workspace, separated by `:`) to make those packages available to the `go` toolchain.

Please refer to [this guide](https://go-team.pages.debian.net/packaging.html#_file_locations) (and look at what `dpkg -L` outputs for any installed Go library package of interest — you'd see the package's import path be actually located under `/usr/share/gocode/src`).

---

(To expand on what @Flimzy suggested in their comment to the original post, and @JimB expanded in theirs…)

You might need to clearly state for yourself what is your intent when you're developing.

The "problem" is that there exists certain disconcert in the approaches Debian and Go take to manage dependencies:

- The common practice suggested by the Go community is to either fix particular versions of your dependencies (these days — via [go modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules)) and let the toolchain fetch and install them for you, or vendor your dependencies — which is logically the same, but in this case you actually carry these dependencies as a part of your codebase (they just sit in a specific directory).

  The former is suggested for library code and generally code which is made available for reusing by third parties, while the latter is typically used by "final" products (usually developed in-house).
- The approach taken by Debian is that of *integration:* they understandably reject the idea of uncontrolled embedding of the dependencies and try to make sure everything which is "reverse-dependent" by anything else is properly packaged, and ideally only a single version of a given library exists in any particular OS release (this is not always possible in real life, though).

Neither of the approaches is ultimately "correct" because they cater for different use cases.

An important thing to consider is that most (if not all) teams writing industry code in Go treat the underlying OS as a boring implementation detail — like, say, a *blob* of "something" which is not too interesting and is merely needed to run the target product (these days, this approach is taken to the extreme through the use of containers) and manage their dependencies themselves.
Why is that?
This is a philosophical question. I think this mostly boils down to the general lack of properly-skilled people in enterprises to do proper integration with the target platform, and at the same time — the ease of maintaining your own tried and tested versions of your dependencies, and not those provided by the distro.

Now let's look at the Debian-packaged Go libraries from another ange.
The Debian packagers solve their integration-centric task by wrapping Go library packages in a way wich makes them available to the Debian's *build helpers* (see [`dh-golang`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/dh-golang)). That is, in Debian, when you prepare a package of some program written in Go, you would inevitably use that `dh-golang` thing which makes sure the Go toolchain is called in a way it could make use of the installed packages.

Now consider that quite a sizeable proportion of Go library code, and many runnable programs are platform-agnostic, *and* if you write Go code which is intended to be of general use, and will hence be published somewhere (like on some of the popular Git hosting solutions), it's much better to keep the code organized in a way that any developer could just grab it and be able to work on it without any special preparations.

So, what I'm leading you to, is that unless you're writing code which will certainly be only used *within* Debian, your approach might to be correct but if you're writing "regular" Go code, I'd recommend to separate the "writing+maintaining code" and "Debian integration" tasks — that is, write your code the way Go community recommends, and then write Debian package which makes use of the installed dependencies.
Note that for the latter you might first need to actually package all the missing dependencies.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! and most importantly, thanks for not being narrow-minded and judgmental!

Comment: @xpt, since I program in Go at my $dayjob, I do share the mindset of those folks who chimed in in the comments to your question (I highly respect them for their expertise; you can trust me on this). But since I'm also a retired Debian maintainer, I tried to provide greater insight on these matters in an edit to my answer. Have fun ;-)

Comment: Thank you for spending time on expending your answers with the caution part. Really appreciate it. It all comes down to -- _"github repos that contains HUGE modules, but what I want is only a tiny/small portion of it"_, people don't believe this part, but I'm not going to justify it just because they don't believe it. I'm going to go ahead and pack that part as a package myself, and maintain it myself. It might show up in Debian repo later or might not... cheers.

Answer (score 1):

While I do understand the whole question very well (as I have exactly the same problem here) I neither understood the comments below it nor the downvoting.  Also the answer with `GOPATH` failed for me, too, like 99% of all other guides about `go` out there.  So I dug into it and found it out the hard way.  (I even watched a Debian build container with systemtap while it ran `dh-golang` .)

## Debian

To use all the modules provided with Debian which are present in `/usr/share/gocode/src` (usually everything I need already is bundled in Debian), all you have to do is

```
ln -s /usr/share/gocode/src vendor
```

> I do not get the latest version of the package, but what Debian has provided.  Which is probably even better at my side.  For me it is crucially important, to be able to prove in future, that this exact code was compiled today.  Hence I cannot depend on something like GitHub, because nobody knows if the repository or the specific checkout still exists in 20 years from now.  But I can make pretty sure, that there still is a mirror of the ancient Debian install archive, such that I (or somebody else) can repeat the exact same steps as of today with exactly the same outcome.  And being offline is a basic requirement for this, too, as else something might get through unnoticed.

## Others

To download some vendor package and use it for my needs, this is nearly the same (YMMV):

```
git submodule add git@my.local.git.server:github.com/$USER/$REPO.git vendor/github.com/$USER/$REPO
```

Which means, I need to prepare the checkout with something like

```
git clone --mirror https://github.com/$USER/$REPO.git
cd $REPO
git push --mirror git@my.local.git.server:github.com/$USER/$REPO.git
```

and then adapt the thingie (usually this means do a code review, as often nothing needs to be changed) on my locally reachable `git` server for my needs.

> Note that I did not test this yet, as I just found out about the `vendor/` directory today.  But I think it should work analogous to what I do elsewhere.  Note that not knowing about `./vendor/` hindered me in the last years to get started with `go`.  Because even the most simple guides and examples out there failed at my side, because there is no such thing like an external network.  (Quite often not even DNS, which once made `npm` to fail, even when it needed no networking at all.)

Note that `git@my.local.git.server:github.com/$USER/$REPO.git` can be some local directory as well created with `git init --bare` of course pre-pushed by some automated provisioning process.

I usually do it the other way round.  So I run

```
git submodule add https://github.com/$USER/$REPO.git
```

which then is mapped by `git` to the real mirrored URL with some rewrite rule like

```
git config --global url.git@my.local.git.server:github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

In the non-networked environment, another rewrite rule can place this into the local filesystem:

```
git config --global url./srv/git/.insteadOf git@my.local.git.server:
```

The important thing here is that there is absolutely no need to alter anything within the repository itself.  Everything can be done from the outside or come from the current individual environment, such that everywhere the same code can be used.

## Why?

To create reproducible builds (which means: Do not depend on network links which may break) and for a little better security control, I usually deactivate external networking when testing and compiling.  This is easily archived by some `nonet` network namespace:

`ip netns add nonet`

then

`ip netns exec nonet /bin/bash`

and then run everything inside.  If some networking is required, this still can be easily mapped into the namespace by (ab)using `haproxy` as a firewall.

> The above commands need `root`, so your `bash` is root as well.  At my side I use [one of my own tools](https://github.com/hilbix/suid/blob/master/suid.conf.d.example/nonet.conf.ex) instead to change into the `nonet` namespace (this line actually is some far too complex workaround, until I find the time to properly build namespaces and the hack `/.fixenv` into `suid` itself) while keeping the user (and security levels).

### Why not Go Proxies?

I simply do not understand that concept of `go` proxies.  Perhaps because I am a strong follower of the standard Unix philosophy:

Everything is filesystem.  (Like `gawk` and `/dev/tcp/`)

Also I am a strong advocate of:

Perfection is reached if you can no more leave something away.

While `git` followed both (The `git` server is a nice-to-have which can be left away.  Everything can be maintained in the filesystem and can equally be archived using filesystem, too), `go` apparently leaves the Unix standard behind for .. I really have no idea what they want to archive with this, besides creating chaos, network instability dependencies and hard to use inflexibility.

> Actually a lie.  `git` followed both principles until Linus was kicked out.  Today we have some horrible new commands like `git restore`, which not only violate the second principle but even make `git` dangerous to use.  (But this is something completely different.)

So a proxy is a proxy and, as the name already says, this is a replacement for something, which can be used for real but is not present for some reason.

Just compare all this text at https://go.dev/ref/mod#goproxy-protocol with a single line of `ln -s /path/to/artifactory vendor`?  Wouldn't it be better to explain the latter?  (Oh, Windows has no softlinks?  Why not?  It's 2023 folks and we have WSL!)

If you ask me, neither Go Proxies nor `vendor/` is sufficient, as the latter has the Highlander problem:  There can only be one.  (But you are in bad company there .. `node_modules`.)

Allowing something like a GoProxy is not a bad thing, but it only is a nice-to-have, not a core feature for me.  `git` already allows basically to rewrite anything to anything using a simple thing like `git config --global url.DESTINATIONPREFIX.insteadOf SOURCEPREFIX`.  While the `git` feature is as simple as it can get (it is so simple that I doubt many people really understand how groundbreaking this is), `go` seams to have a similar feature, which, sorry, I was not able to understand even when I tried.  AFAICS it is far from being as flexible as this simple `git` construct.

What I want to say with this:  `go` has the possibility to pull things out of a VCS.  Why?  Wouldn't it be much better to base this all just on top of  some powerful VCS like `git`?  `git` already knows of `git submodule`, so if `go` would utilize the `git` filesystem, there is no need for a file named `go.sum`.  But instead, `go` re-invents a wheel, which - my taste - is something more like a flat tire.  YMMV.

What really makes me angry is, that the documentation of `go` apparently hides the `vendor` feature so well.  I did not find a suitable documentation about it, even that I now know, what to google for!  All there is is something about "vendoring", but even with this documentation, I do not understand what they want to tell me.  It reads more like a bundling tool than a way to provide missing artifacts in a non-networked environment.  And the non-network environment still should be the main case!  Or do your toilet and water tap talk IP?  (Some of mine already do!  Home automation ..  Sigh)