# golang offline install third party package

Tags: go, package, offline

I'm trying to install third party package of golang in offline.
I want to do something like go get  in an online environment in an offline environment. I can get the source of the third party package from github and put it in an offline environment, but then I can't use it as a package in golang.

What should i do?

Comment: may help https://gist.github.com/gmolveau/f09c1038ca622620e54d0579ba06ea96

Answer (score 2):

As @emptyhua commented, this link worked for me: https://gist.github.com/gmolveau/f09c1038ca622620e54d0579ba06ea96#file-golang_offline-md

For reference here:

1. On the online machine ensure go.mod and go.sum exist in current dir
   create a go file with:

```
import (
    _ "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {}
```

2. run: `go mod vendor`
3. Copy go.mod, go.sum and vendor directory to the offline machine
4. run: `go run -mod=vendor main.go`

To test offline, I used a container with no network:
`podman run --rm -it --net none -v $(pwd):/go/src:z golang`

```
cd src
go run -mod=vendor main.go
```

Hope that helps! Thanks @gmolveau - [offline go mods](https://gist.github.com/gmolveau/f09c1038ca622620e54d0579ba06ea96#file-golang_offline-md)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `vendor/` directory.

See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76688264/490291

If the package is part of Debian, perhaps even following is enough:

```bash
ln -s /usr/share/gocode/src vendor
```

A package `github.com/$USER/$REPO` is searched at `vendor/github.com/$USER/$REPO/`, such that you can even use `git submodule` for checking out the package:

```bash
git submodule add https://github.com/$USER/$REPO.git vendor/github.com/$USER/$REPO/
```

> AFAICS (but I never tried it) `git submodule update --recursive` does not work here as expected.  So if some submodule has a `vendor/` directory itself, you must mix this into your own `vendor/` directory, as this feature does not do recursion.  At least that is the impression I got from the (too scarce) documentation about that feature.
>
> You can use softlinks to map the sub-paths, of course, like with
>
> ```bash
> yes n | for a in vendor/*/*/*/vendor/*; do [ -d "$a" ] && ln -is --relative "$a"/* "vendor/`basename "$a"`/"; done
> ```

There is a less known `git` feature which allows you to map any URL to anything.  So for example if you did a mirror (something you can copy to your servers with your provisioning tool or `rsync`):

```bash
git clone --mirror https://github.com/$USER/$REPO.git /srv/git/github.com/$USER/$REPO.git
```

you can map `https://github.com/$USER/$REPO.git` to `/srv/git/github.com/$USER/$REPO.git` with a single line:

```bash
git config --global url./srv/git/github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

> So:
>
> - On some remote networked PC do all the `--mirror` cloning
> - Copy the mirrored repositories to `/srv/git/` on the offlined PC
> - Then do `git config --global url./srv/git/.insteadOf https://`
> - Then do the `git submodule add` into `vendor/`
>
> Or `git clone --recursive /srv/git/yoursource.git` which already has the `.gitmodules` file in place, which carries `https://github.com/`-URLs which only work outside of the offline environment, but work offline, too, as they are remapped to `/srv/git/`

Note that you can map all `http://` and `https://` URLs this way, such that `https://$SERVER/$USER/$REPO.git` becomes `/srv/git/$SERVER/$USER/$REPO.git` with

```bash
git config --global url./srv/git/.insteadOf https://
git config --global url./srv/git/.insteadOf http://
```

The only thing you need to remember is:  **Do not leave the suffix `.git` away** in your checkouts/submodule URLs.  And do not add a trailing `/`.

This usually makes live much easier.  Because you usually want to name "bare" `git` repositories (`--mirror`) `something.git` and not `something`, as usually `something/` should be the checkout of a worktree.  As `git` is intelligent enough to remove the `.git` in most cases, and all `git` services like GitHub or GitLab do this, too, adding the `.git` only adds benefits when remapping, because you can map `something.git` and `something-wiki.git` differently (without extension `something` includes `something-wiki`).

The `git` feature `url.*.insteadOf` only maps the prefix, you cannot change the suffix as easily as well.  So if you happen to need to add a suffix, you must remap each URL individually, which makes things uncomfortable.  Also I consider ending `git` repo URLs on `.git` to look much more natural.  YMMV.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you have to set the `GOPATH` for the working directory.
After then you can use the following offline package just you have to create a `mod` file for the path of the packages.

Initialize go mod file using below code

`go mod init <Enter your GitHub profile link>`

For example:

`go mod init github.com/amshashankk`

after this when you import the packages they will be written as following in the import section of the code

`github.com/amshashankk/package`.

Comment: You do not need to set GOPATH to work with modules, and it should never be set to your module directory.

Comment: Well GOPATH is set already when you download Go on your machine. In case if it says path error then you have to configure the GOPATH for the working directory where your all projects are build.